# C++ / XCode - How to generate pdfs?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, pdf

I need to generate a pdf from a c++ application. I am using Xcode and I would like to stick to that. Possibly the solution needs to be opensource. I already tried a few, but ecountered issues:

I tried podofo but I had some issues when building it - it seems that does not work on OS X.

I wanted to use ClibPDF, but that is no more available for download.

When including PDFlib oder PDFlib Lite in my projects that does not work either, I get some strange memory errors on runtime.

Has anyone an idea what could be used with C++/XCode for pdfs? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/02/13/Generate-PDF-on-iPhone.aspx  Are you against using Obj-C?

Comment: Hi, the technology must be C++...its a given part of the project.

Comment: Is this homework or is there really a company that's Mac-only but refuses to use the standard APIs for things?

Comment: I've added the homework tag.  Please be more detailed on what you are or are not allowed to use.  Personally, I'm using libharu, which was written in C.

Comment: I've tried libharu too, but I had a lot of warnings and errors when doing "make"...errors like src/hpdf_image_png.c:20:17: error: png.h: No such file or directory
src/hpdf_image_png.c:23: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘png_ptr’
src/hpdf_image_png.c:28: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘png_ptr’
src/hpdf_image_png.c:46: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘png_ptr’
src/hpdf_image_png.c:52: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘png_structp’

Answer (score 1):

To create a podfo Xcode project use the following in Terminal:

```
cmake -G "Xcode" -DWANT_FONTCONFIG:BOOL=YES -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/podofo -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH=/opt/local/include -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/local/lib ../podofoSrcDir
```

Answer (score 0):

The Mac OS X drawing library, Quartz, [supports PDF natively](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I had a look at Quartz too, but in the end I implemented it with QT (which I was using anyways) as I found out that it provides such a feature. Seems to work well!